# Grid / Popup editing

Tags: gridview, data-binding, kendo-ui, popup, office365

I have a kendo grid list view from office 365. I tried to create a custom list view in SharePoint Online. I was able to read and delete data but when I click update nothing happens. Here is [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MyTD.png) followed by the relevant code.

```
grid.bind("edit", EditItem);
function EditItem(e) {
    var numeric = e.container.find("input[name=ID]").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
    numeric.enable(false);
    var Title = e.container.find("input[name=Title")[0].value;
    var ID= e.container.find("input[name=ID")[0].value;
    $('a.k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-update').click(function () {
        alert(Title+" *****" +ID);
    });
    alert(Title);` `if (Title != null) {
        $.ajax({
            url: appWebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + MyTaskValue + "')/items(" + ID + ")",
            data: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.MyTaskValueListItem' }, 'Title': Title },
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE",
                "If-Match": "*"
            },
            success: function (data) {` 

                alert("Item updated successfully!");
                              },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Failed to update');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is this a typo?  var Title = e.container.find("input[name=Title")[0].value;
        var ID= e.container.find("input[name=ID")[0].value;  should it not be  `input[name=Title"]` (notice bracket difference)

Answer (score 0):

As per the console error in the screenshot, "]" is missing. use below line

```
var Title = e.container.find("input[name=Title]")[0].value;
```